# Rails: find all parents with all children having a particular attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to find all Parents that have ALL children with a status = 1.

If one of the children is not status = 1; then parent is not selected.

```
class Parent
  has_many :children
end

class Child
  status = [ 0, 1 ]
end
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
Parent.left_outer_joins(:children).where("children.status = ?", 1)
```

It doesn't work because I still get Parent with children status=0

Comment: whats you mean by `it doesn't work.` did you face any error or issue with that query?

Comment: @Gabbar It doesn't work because I still get Parent with children status=0

Comment: is `status` enum?

Comment: @Gabbar yes it's enum

Comment: Join is not enough in your case, I guess. "All children have status 1" is equivalent to "There are no children with status 0". So you need a query like `select * from parents p where not exists (select 1 from children c where c.parent_id = p.id and status = 0)` - not sure if it's possible to build it with AR query interface. AREL magic might help maybe, but to be honest in practice I'd prefer pure SQL - as more readable and straightforward...

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need a subquery:

```
Parent.where.not(id: Children.where.not(status: 1).select(:parent_id))
```

Comment: I just updated my answer because it was incorrect. Feel free to try this one instead :))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Parent.where("id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(parent_id) FROM children WHERE children.status =1)")
```

Hope you'll find this helpful!!!

Answer (score -1):

I think you could do something like this:

```
Parent.joins(:children).where.not(
  id: Child.where(status: :closed).select('DISTINCT "parent_id"')
).distinct
```

Comment: But, this doesn't only show parents where _all_ of the children are closed. If _any_ of the children are closed it will show the parent here.